# Chrome element inspector does not align with actual rendered element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When viewing the following navbar with the Chrome element inspector, the highlighted elements are not where the actual elements are rendered. Why exactly is this happening?

https://codepen.io/bbbenji/pen/OodrJr (sorry, too much code to post here)

This only happens in Chrome on both Linux and Windows. Firefox does not have this issue.

[image]

```
Too much code to post on Stackoverflow.
Codepen link provided above.
```

Comment: May i ask what a #DIV_5 { display: -webkit-box; } is supposed to do? I couldn't find any documentation about it and it seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: @Mirous This is basically ripped code from some website. I haven't really dived into it. I am not trying to fix this error, just wanted to find out why this is happening.

Comment: @Mirous `display: -webkit-box;` is old flexbox syntax

Answer (score 0):

I found out that #DIV_5 { display: -webkit-box; } (which is causing the problem) is supposed to be some predecessor of display: flex;. It's prefixed with -webkit- so it targets only Chrome like browsers. I'm pretty sure what it does it is trying to use some older spec, but that spec doesn't work well with #DIV_6 { float: left; } and make even the inspector buggy.